# Android AdMob crashes app on start

Tags: crash, admob

I don't what's wrong with this code but AdMob crashes the App. I made a new project with just AdMob in it and it still crashes. Any ideas?

I imported the AdMob .jar rightclick project > Properties > Java Build Path > add external JARs and added the GoogleAdMobAdsSdk...jar

layout xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<com.google.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adUnitId="12345678901234567890"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" />
</LinearLayout>
```

main java:

```
package com.example.admob;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.google.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.ads.AdView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
AdView adView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    AdRequest adR = new AdRequest();
    adR.addTestDevice("4df1559f64826fed");
    adView = (AdView)findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
    adView.loadAd(adR);

}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    if (adView != null) {
        adView.destroy();
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

}

Please help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is:

```
adView = (AdView)findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
```

Instead you want:

```
adView = (AdView)findViewById(R.id.adView);
```

to find the AdView instead of the LinearLayout. You're app is crashing because you're trying to cast a LinearLayout to an AdView.

I recommend you view the LogCat output from Android so you can see why it's complaining. It'll be a useful tool as you start working with Android. You can add it into Eclipse via:

```
Window -> Show View -> Other... -> Android/Logcat
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I activated the logcat but it won't show anything during debug :/

Comment: Check the saved filters on the left and make sure you have the right app selected (or just go to All messages). You can also add the `Devices` view from the same area you added LogCat. If you have multiple emulators/devices, make sure you've selected the right device as well.

Comment: You're Java file is using the new Google Play services APIs, but your XML and manifest are still pointing to com.google.ads.AdView and com.google.ads.AdActivity. You should change these to the new package, com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView and AdActivity.